# R proxy https certificate error

Tags: r

I use RStudio and am behind a company firewall and have set up the .Renviron file as:

```
options(internet.info = 0)

http_proxy="http://user:pw@proxy:port"
http_proxy_user="user:pw"
https_proxy="https://user:pw@proxy:port"
https_proxy_user="user:pw"
```

library(httr)

If I run this:

```
raw.result <- GET(url = "http://www.example.com/")
```

It works but if I run this

```
raw.result <- GET(url = "https://www.example.com/")
```

I keep getting this error:

```
Error in curl::curl_fetch_memory(url, handle = handle) : 
  error setting certificate verify locations:
  CAfile: /mingw64/ssl/certs/ca-bundle.crt
  CApath: none
```

I've tried looking for solutions, but can't figure out why this is.

Comment: are you using windows?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to set the https proxy as a system environment variable and not a R variable.

```
#if you are using Windows you can use this to get the proxy server and port
companyproxy <- curl::ie_proxy_info()$Proxy

#set http proxy due to company's firewall
Sys.setenv(http_proxy=companyproxy)
Sys.setenv(https_proxy=companyproxy)

#GET a https website
raw.result <- GET(url="https://httpbin.org")
```

Reference:
https://github.com/jeroen/curl/issues/116

Comment: My ie_proxy_info() is blank but I ended up using curl_fetch_memory with a handle to make it work.